# Django form that updates multiple records

Tags: html, django, django-forms, permissions, crud

I have 2 classes of users who can view a screen that lists all users in my app.  The type of user is controlled by a Boolean field on the User model. The screen currently lists out the Users and various details about them  (see below).  Project Managers should see a read only view of the page where as Administrators should have the ability to edit the Users as well.

[image]

HTML for the screen.

```
               <div class="card-body">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table text-sm mb-0">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>#</th>
                      <th>Username</th>
                      <th>First Name</th>
                      <th>Last Name</th>
                      <th>Is Contributor?</th>
                      <th>Is Project Manager?</th>
                      <th>Is is_administrator?</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    {% for user in users %}
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">{{ user.id }}</th>
                      <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
                      <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href=" " role="button">{{ user.first_name }}</a></td>
                      <td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
                      <td>{{ user.is_contributor }}</td>
                      <td>{{ user.is_projectmanager }}</td>
                      <td>{{ user.is_administrator }}</td>
                      <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="" role="button">Edit</a></td>
                      <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="" role="button">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
```

I want to create a version of the screen available to admin users which allows them to view and update users all at once.

How can I create a form that updates all the users at once?  I'm looking to build something that lists out the users with a list of the fields associated with the model and then gives the admin the ability to change those fields for multiple users at the same time, and then hit a save button to submit the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out using Model form sets.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

I just created the form set as seen below.

```
    UserFormSet = modelformset_factory(User,fields=('username','first_name','last_name','email','is_contributor','is_projectmanager','is_administrator'))
formset = UserFormSet()
context = {
    # 'users':users,
    'formset':formset,
}
return render(request, 'bugtracker_app/users.html', context)
```

Then I looped through it in the template:

```
                </div>
            {% for form in formset %}
            {{form}}
          {% endfor %}
          </div>
```

It isn't formatted quiet the way I was picturing it yet (it renders the fields vertically as opposed to horizontally see below, but I'm sure I can find a way to fix that.

[image]